# Selecionar várias classes CSS com coringa

Tags: html, css

Quero colorir todas as classes de um grid que baixei, o Flexbox.

Ele tem 12 colunas, quero fazer algo do tipo `col-md-*` e selecionar todos que usam essa classe para colorir.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Solução CSS3

Como hoje em dia o CSS3 é aceito pela esmagadora maioria dos *browsers*, você pode fazer isto com seletor de atributo:

```
div[class^="col-md-"] {
   color:red 
}
```

Mas CUIDADO que o exemplo acima não pega isso:

```
<div class="batata col-md-3">
```

pois ele não está considerando as classes, e sim as *strings*.

Para ficar completo, pode usar isto:

```
div[class^="col-md-"], div[class*=" col-md-"] {
   color:red;
}
```

Muita atenção com o espaço antes de `col` no segundo caso. Basicamente estamos dizendo isto:

- `class^="col-md-"`: o atributo `class` começa com `col-md-`

  OU
- `class*=" col-md-"`: o atributo `class` contém `col-md-` (com espaço no começo)

### Solução CSS2 (trabalhosa para o autor, leve para o *browser*)

Para ficar compatível com CSS2, só listando tudo manualmente, desta forma:

```
   col-md-1,
   col-md-2,
   col-md-3,
   col-md-4,
   ... listar todos possíveis separados por vírgula ...
   col-md-12 {
     color: red;
   }
```

A vantagem desta é que "facilita a vida" do navegador, evitando operações complexas para aplicação dos estilos ao montar a página.

Comment: Muito obrigado, amigo!