# Identificar CSS anterior

Tags: css

É possível identificar CSS anterior?

O foco aqui é a class `card`.

Exemplo:

```
<div class="app">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="card">
                <label for="">Titulo</label>
                <div class="number">
                    120
                </div>
    
                <div class="number">
                    Bla bla bla
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="sm-6 md-6 lg-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <label for="">Titulo</label>
                    <div class="number">
                        120
                    </div>
        
                    <div class="number">
                        Bla bla bla
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Na `primeira row` a class `card` está sozinha. Na `segunda row` a class name está dentro de uma coluna representada pelas class `sm-6 md-6 lg-6`.

**PERGUNTA**

É possível aplicar um CSS ao `card` que está apenas em `sm, md ou lg`?

Obrigado.

Comment: @hkotsubo não, no meu caso é o inverso, gostaria de verificar para traz.

Comment: Vc não quer estilizar o card que está dentro do sm? Então seria algo como `.sm-6  > .card` (ou sem o `>`, como explicado no link que indiquei). Ou vc quer estilizar o sm, desde que tenha um card dentro? Nesse caso, acho que seria duplicada dessa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/510083/112052

Comment: Tem como identificar apenas pelas letras? Exemplo VOU INVENTAR: `.sm*, md*, lg* .card`?

Comment: Aí teria que ser algo [assim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175300/112052) - mas como não tem "ou", teria que ser um pro sm, outro pro md, etc - mas ainda não ficou claro, vc quer selecionar o card ou o pai dele?

Comment: [Problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/137387), você está complicado uma coisa simples.  Veja na perguta indicada como duplicada como selecionar um elemento descendente de outro baseado em suas classes `[class="sm-6 md-6 lg-6"] > [class="card"]{  color: red; }`

Answer (score -2):

Solução:

```
div[class^="sm-"] > .card, div[class^="md-"] > .card, div[class^="lg-"] > .card { ... }
```